# Arrow keys does not work in cscope in Terminal on Macos

Tags: macos, terminal

I am running `cscope` in Terminal on MacOS by using `cscope -d`.
But the arrow keys ( <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> ) do not work, as I need to navigate from 1 query to another.

Can you please tell me how can I fix that?

Comment: They work fine for me...

Comment: I can only get `^P` and `^J` to work, as described in one of the answers below. It would be nice if they arrow keys just worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> for up key and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> for down keys.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal.app gets a little weird about keys; are you using the arrow keys on the numeric keypad?  If so, those will always map to digits whether or not you've got the NumLock turned on.

If not, try shift-arrow.

Comment: i am using the actual arrow keys. Using shift-arrow does not work either. I need to navigate up/down by using Ctrl-N, Ctrl-P now. I am hoping arrow keys work.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue.  term is xterm, arrow work for bash, its just cscope? ^J and enter work for down, but no up.  I can hit down several times and it loops to the top, but it would be nice to be able to map my arrow keys to something?